# Is there a way to create an AWS ALB referring to k8s nginx ingress on another AWS account?

Tags: kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

Our partner company running an EKS cluster on their own AWS account, and part of our app services also running in the cluster. and currently they're using nginx ingress controller to routing the services, including ours. the controller routing service by hostname(domain name).
For now they exposed the controller with an internal nlb (but seems not using it, maybe), and created several alb with acm certificates separately for other services, by attaching the auto scaling groups of EKS cluster to the alb.

I think this also work for us, but need to deploy our alb and acm certificates on their account.
we don't want to deploy our acm certificates on the account out of ours, so my question is there a way to do this but keep acm certificates deployed on our own account? alb could be deployed on anhywhere, only concern the acm certificates.
btw we could ask our partner to make some change on the k8s/controller if necessary.

thank you!

I tried deploy alb on our own account and attaching the auto scaling groups of EKS cluster but failed, seems the auto scaling groups and the alb need to be the same account, the same vpc.